Regional information in ID questions is being ignored
A common pratice in the Gardening and Landscaping network is for location information to be solicited from the questioner in order to help identify plants, give tailored growing advice for the climate, or whatever.
My opinion is that this network could benefit from the same thing with its identify questions.
A common frustration I have when I come here is that people from all over the world are asking questions about movies and shows I've never heard of, and I don't know where to look for answers. However, if we knew where in the world they were coming from, that could help tremendously. I mean, at least I would know if it's something I ought to have heard of or not (and it would make the site a lot more educational).
Anyway, do you think pressing people about location information (where they were in the world when they saw the show or movie) here would be a good idea or not? What are your thoughts on the matter (not just whether it's good or bad)?

Yes, this is already included in the list of additional details that are recommended for story-ID askers to supply (and for other users to potentially ask them in comments if they didn't supply):

The language you read or heard the story in

In what country?
The language the story was originally written in (if different), and any information you might have about translations into other languages


From the meta FAQ on good story-ID questions and in a shorter form in the tag wiki for the story-ID tag. I'm not sure why you say this type of information "is being ignored".

I think he means "being ignored by the asker/s"

Both of those details can be extremely useful. Language sometimes cues a search in that language, for example, or recognizing a false cognate (for example, a past question with a boy finding a portal in a "cave" in his house made a lot more sense once it was noted to be French, where "cave" means "basement"). Knowing location can help narrow down network offerings. Cartoon Network India runs different shows than Cartoon Network in the United States.

Despite my best efforts, not everyone can be an expert on everything. When I see someone asking a question about a film or a show from a culture other than my own, I might spend a few seconds googling to see if it's a simple fix, or if someone has asked (and answered) the question elsewhere, but usually my next action is to move onto something that I do know about, rather than embarrassing myself by confidently stating that the answer is "X" only to then be corrected by someone who actually knows what they're talking about :-)
Questions about non-English properties are pretty rare (we are, after all, an English-language site) and most of those tend to be about things that have been subbed or shown in English-speaking countries with subtitles and localisation.
In short, demanding location info for every question would be excessive, and questions about non-English properties are usually extremely easy to spot. If you don't know where to even look for an answer, you should probably leave the question to people who do.
